# Trouble Dealing With exacttarget List...without DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, list, ssjs

We have a situation where get subscriberkey/email address from ET email and external site and i  retrieve subscribers attributes IN THE LANDING PAGE (Hosted in the exacttarget) fields from the Exact-target Lists (There is no DE).

a.      Tried lookup Ampscript function but FAILED …..(lookup may work only for DE not lists…may be?) things unclear but I tried : [LookupRows in All Subscribers?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31527/lookuprows-in-all-subscribers)

b.      Tried  AMPscript API and still can’t access to List attributes. [Exacttarget : AMPscript API - InvokeRetrieve failed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53919/exacttarget-ampscript-api-invokeretrieve-failed/53958?noredirect=1#comment71043_53958)

c.      Even tried SSJS but here when we use filter as status = active , then I get  only status,emailaddress,createdate and other attributes as UNDEFINED but if i change the filter for example (Region = Finland) we get nothing.. 
[Failure to retrieve list subscriber attributes in a landing page using AMPScript and SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49367/exacttarget-fail-to-retrieve-list-subscribers-attributes-in-a-landing-page-api)

What I realize :

1. while using SSJS, that somehow with SSJS I can access only limited field attributes from the list Not the custom ones* (can check the link from (c.) for details)
2. With AMPscript  API, can just get the count but no access to the attributes.. (can check the link from (b.)(c.) for details)
3. With lookup function, hard to say it works with lists.
4. NOW WONDER IS IT ACCOUNT RELATED ? we USE CORE EDITION OF EXACTTARGET.

pointers are appreciated.

Comment: How and where are you trying to retrieve these?  Are you trying to pull them into an email, retrieve them on a landing page or external site, or are you trying to retrieve them via API?

Comment: I pass the subscriber key (Unique) from email to LP and retrieve the subscribers list attributes in the Landing page.

Comment: Also, I get subscriber key  from external  site and i try to retrieve the subscriber list attributes from ET to the same LP's

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you're deploying emails from ExactTarget.  If your email has a link to the landing page, you can set up that link to allow those parameters (attributes) automatically to be passed through when sending to a list.

Here's [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54077/landing-page-not-populating-with-subscriber-data) where this was addressed.  You would use the MicrositeURL() Ampscript function and reference your landing page ID, that when clicked, takes a subscriber to that landing page.  Within your landing page, it's then just as simple as inserting the attribute name like:  %%attributename%% - that attribute then will be automatically populated with whatever the subscriber currently has within your ET Account.

Your link in the email would like similar to the below.  Also included the Help Link to Landing Page AMPScript functions.  Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

```
<a title="page" href="%%=MicrositeURL(12345)=%%" alias="LP" conversion="false">PageLink</a>
```

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/

Comment: how about retrieving the attributes values via subscriber key coming from external site rather than email?? any pointer?